# How to get actual strings from a Node property in Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

How do I go about getting an unformatted string from a Node in neo 4J? I have tried the return str or, return 1. But it always formats it in database style. What I need to do is compare user input in the form of a string to a Nodes property but it cant be done due to the formatting. 
What kind of query would I use in java to get a raw String or Int?

```
+-------------+
| str("test") |
+-------------+
| ""test""    |
+-------------+
```

Comment: You tagged this with [tag:java], yet you're showing shell output. If you're attempting to work via Java, you should show your code. Otherwise, the Java tag is incorrect here.

Comment: The query is being executed in java ( netbeans ) Also as I mentioned im trying to compare that result to a input string, In java.

 Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put( "id", 0 );
        String query = "MATCH  (n {root:\"true\"}) return str(\"test\")";
        Result result = graphDb.execute( query);
        
        while(result.hasNext()){    
            System.out.println(result.resultAsString());
        }

there is the code.

Comment: Please don't bury code in comments. It's difficult to read. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `resultAsString()`, that simply formats the entire result as a String.

Instead, extract the column that you're interested in-

```
String query = "MATCH (n {root:\"true\"}) return str(\"test\") as strval";
Result result = graphDb.execute(query); 
Iterator<String> strval = result.columnAs("strval");
for (String str : IteratorUtil.asIterable(strval)) {
   System.out.println(str);
}
```

Other ways of accessing the results: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-cypher-java.html and http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Result.html

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you can't do it. Most other sql-like shells allow command-line flags that disable the table output format, but the neo4j shell does not provide this functionality.

Answer (score -1):

The output you're showing is generated specifically in the Neo4j shell. Just as the web viewer has its own formatting. Text is not formatted like that when making programmatic calls, which is how you'd need to create queries in an app anyway.